# Expansion of joomla site

Tags: joomla

I have a requirement to build one parent site and few child sites..using domain and sub-domain concept and want to have installations of joomla at parent and all sub-domains. But I want only my parent site to hold user data and Alpha user points data while my child sites would be hosting components and modules separately and use user data and Alpha user points data from parent site.

Could any one suggest me is it a good Architecture to go and is there any extension or component already available to achieve it. Example
below:

parent site movies.com Child sites braveheart.movies.com, troy.movies.com

I will have forums, blogs and other component installations at braveheart and troy sub-domains seperately while my Alpha user points and users db/tables would reside at movies.com(main domain).

It's like single-sign on or Centralised Alhpa user points, but free to install same component and modules at different sub-domains.

Highly appreciate any replies or solutions proposed

Answer (score 0):

I would have recommended this: http://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation (yes it's old but with little modification you can make it work on the latest version of Joomla) but the problem is that you want to install extensions to these subdomains as well, which will mess up the parent structure.

I think Joomla is not the best choice for what you want to do - Wordpress handles the multiple domain thing much more elegantly and gracefully.

PS: There are also some extensions that do more or less what you want. Check here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/7557

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using the same version of Joomla across all sites, and all the **DBs are on one server**, one method would be to keep the parent user and alpha points tables, drop the tables on the child sites, and replace them with table views from the parent database. Then you just need to do a bit of tweaking to handle bridged sessions.

Basically, the child sites think they've got their own tables, when actually you've tricked them into using the parent DB user tables.

Reference:
http://www.ijoomla.com/blog/one-set-of-joomla-users-multiple-joomla-installs/

This is for Joomla 1.5, but the process is transferable for 2/3.x, **if you know what you're doing**. No need for installing a bunch of extensions.

If you're going to try this method (keep in mind you need to have a **good handle on MySQL manipulation and Joomla**), make sure you **back your sites up.**

If you're not confident, the reference above goes through a bunch of alternatives.